Why does plain TeX backtrack by the depth of box 255 for ragged bottom layout?
According to Chapter 23 of the TeXbook, \pagecontents is defined as:
\ifvoid\topins \else\unvbox\topins\fi
\dimen0=\dp255 \unvbox255
\ifvoid\footins\else % footnote info is present
  \vskip\skip\footins
  \footnoterule
  \unvbox\footins\fi
\ifraggedbottom \kern-\dimen0 \vfil \fi

Why is \dimen0=\dp255 … \kern-\dimen0 necessary here?

Note that \pagecontents is used in the context:
\vbox to\vsize{\pagecontents}

If the box255 has its last line with non-zero depth then it isn't counted to the total \vsize of the resulting box. The resulting box has its height equal to \vsize, no height plus depth.
If the \raggedbottom is set then the \pagecontents includes a new item at its bottom: \vfil. The resulting height of this box (without stretching) is equal to box plus depth of original box255 because \vfil is added after the depth of the last line. But we want to insert the \pagecontents to the same \vsize as in the previous case. This is the reason why we substract the depth of box255 before putting it to the \vbox to\vsize.

Thank you, that makes sense. But if there are footnotes, shouldn't the depth of the \footins box be subtracted instead? Is it simply assumed that \raggedbottom isn't used with footnotes?
